# Error: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException When get Arraylist from database

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get locations name in ArrayList from database table `supply_location`. But i have an error:

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

**VendorBean:**

```
public class VendorBean {
    private String supplyLocation[];

    public void setSupplyLocation(String[] supplyLocation) {
       this.supplyLocation=supplyLocation;
    }
    public String[] getSupplyLocation() {
       return supplyLocation;
    }
}
```

**DAO:**

```
public List<VendorBean> getLocation(String supplyLocation) throws SQLException {

        ArrayList<VendorBean> SupplyLocation = new ArrayList<VendorBean>();

        try {
            String userID = supplyLocation;
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String query  = "SELECT location_name FROM supply_location AS sl\n" +
                                   "LEFT JOIN user_signup AS us \n" +
                                   "ON sl.user_id = us.user_id WHERE us.user_id = ?";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, userID);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                VendorBean supplyLoc = new VendorBean();
                Array a = rs.getArray("location_name");
                String[] location = (String[])a.getArray();

                supplyLoc.setSupplyLocation(location);
                SupplyLocation.add(supplyLoc);
            }
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if(rs!=null) {
                   rs.close();
                }
                if (ps!=null) {
                   ps.close();
                }
                if(con!=null) {
                   con.close();
                }
            }  catch (SQLException ex) {
                    //ignore
            }
        }
        return SupplyLocation;
    }
```

I want to retrieve the location_name from database in this format:

```
1. location_name1 
2. location_name2
3. location_name3
4. location_name4
5. location_name5
```

I have search many time for this issue, but didn't get proper solution. Please anyone help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLFeatureNotSupportedException on getArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735786/sqlfeaturenotsupportedexception-on-getarray)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you database does not support ARRAY column type. See question [SQLFeatureNotSupportedException on getArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735786/sqlfeaturenotsupportedexception-on-getarray)